# can't run sqldeveloper on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, sqldeveloper

I tried to install `sqldeveloper` by following way:

```
Download SQL Developer from Oracle website (I chose Other Platforms download).

Extract file to /opt:

sudo unzip sqldeveloper-*-no-jre.zip -d /opt/
sudo chmod +x /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh
Linking over an in-path launcher for Oracle SQL Developer:

sudo ln -s /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper
Edit /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper.sh replace it's content to:

#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
./sqldeveloper "$@"
Run SQL Developer:

sqldeveloper
```

But it shows next output:

```
nazar@lelyak-desktop:/opt/sqldeveloper⟫ ./sqldeveloper.sh 

 Oracle SQL Developer
 Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.    

 LOAD TIME : 401#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3b2dcacbe0, pid=20351, tid=139892273444608
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_65-b17) (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00007f3b2dcacbe0
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/core or core.20351
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid20351.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin/../../ide/bin/launcher.sh: line 1193: 20351 Aborted                 (core dumped) ${JAVA} "${APP_VM_OPTS[@]}" ${APP_ENV_VARS} -classpath ${APP_CLASSPATH} ${APP_MAIN_CLASS} "${APP_APP_OPTS[@]}"
134 nazar@lelyak-desktop:/opt/sqldeveloper⟫ java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Here is content of [/tmp/hs_err_pid20351.log](http://pastebin.com/wpHgAAKm)

***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also affected but found solution [here](http://ivanbabanin.blogspot.cz/2014/02/sqldeveloper-4-crash-jvm-on-startup.html).

> Solution is simple, before launch sh sqldeveloper.sh unset environment variable `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` or you can create another launcher.sh like this: 
>   
>   `unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
>   sh sqldeveloper.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same problem and have not yet resolved the issue.  I found this [post](http://blog.jorisvisscher.com/2014/08/12/oracle-sql-developer-4-does-not-run-on-oracle-java-7-on-ubuntu-14-04/#comment-152) with suggestions.

1) Install OpenJDK

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

2) Open the configuration file

```
vim ~/.sqldeveloper/4.0.0/product.conf
```

3) Change

---

EDIT:

I had to remove OpenJDK and reinstall for it to work for me. I think there was something with the links.

```
SetJavaHome /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I reinstalled open-jdk, too.

Comment: @nazar_art did you set the deault jvm?

Comment: Yes, of course. I did it. Reinstall `open JDK` and tried again. It keep throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just had to set **SetJavaHome** entry with the path for the JDK in the *~/.sqldeveloper/4.1.0/product.conf* and it worked like a charm.