# How to run correctly bash script from another script?

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, sqldeveloper

I want to run [sqldeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.

I created some symbolic link and tried to call from one script file another.

And it fail with message:

> /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper: line 2: cd: /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper/bin: Not a directory

Here is my spteps:

```
Linking over an in-path launcher for Oracle SQL Developer:

sudo ln -s /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper

Edit /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper.sh replace it's content to:

#!/bin/bash
unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
sh sqldeveloper_launcher.sh
```

Content of `sqldeveloper_launcher.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
./sqldeveloper "$@"
```

Run SQL Developer is next:

```
sqldeveloper
```

But if I put content of `sqldeveloper_launcher.sh` into `sqldeveloper.sh` it works (it means that it really running sqldeveloper, but it fails at runtime with error [can't run sqldeveloper on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499372/cant-run-sqldeveloper-on-ubuntu/518653#518653)).

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: I'm little bit confused, anyway, `sqldeveloper_laucher.sh` is bash script and you invoke it with `sh`, you should use bash instead or `.`. After this, the error you got seems due to some broken link, try `namei -mo /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin` and finally I guess that step: `Edit /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper.sh replace it's content to:` really was `Edit /usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper replace it's content to:` isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
    cd /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
    unset GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_FALLBACK
    ./sqldeveloper "$@"
```

This will fix your problem

Comment: Could you add a little context/explanation why that works?